# Apache2 can't use SSL after upgrade

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl

After a global upgrade (apt-get upgrade) Apache2 won't work with SSL anymore.

> Ubuntu 16
>
> Apache version : 2.4.37
>
> OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 1.1.1-pre7 (beta) 29 May 2018
>
> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib

When I try to start the service I get the following error:

> Dec 12 18:43:59 labo apachectl[1677]: apache2: Syntax error on line
> 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 2 of
> /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.load: Cannot load
> /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so into server:
> /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so: symbol
> SSL_CTX_set_post_handshake_auth, version OPENSSL_1_1_1 not defined in
> file libssl.so.1.1 with link time reference

If I disable ssl from apache2 I can successfully start the service.

I tried to reinstall apache2 & openssl, it doesn't get any better.

---

## Solved

**Found the problem**:

The OpenSSL version I was using was the wrong one. I compiled OpenSSL1.1.1-pre7 several months ago to fit some security requirements. Apparently the upgrade didn't update OpenSSL to the good version (OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018).

the following steps made the correction:

```
~# sudo a2dismod ssl
~# sudo apt-get purge openssl
~/openssl-1.1.1-pre7# make uninstall //Uninstall the version I build
~# sudo apt-get install openssl
~# sudo a2enmod ssl
```

Comment: Make sure your dev (or devel) packages are installed for the same versions as the running software.  You should check that mod_ssl.so was compiled with the same version as the OpenSSL you install on your server.  I always compile my own Apache to avoid this...

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer of its own, thank you.